# Python -> Tkinker -> TopLevel - auto size but with minimum width

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

I have a TopLevel(elements with Tkinker libiary) that has dynamically generated and added new items. The window adapts perfectly to the elements in height and width and I do not want to set a constant. However, the width is always a bit too narrow, so the elements fit, but the window looks bad.

Is it possible to set a minimum width or add permanent margins on the sides?

(Python 3)

Comment: Please [edit]  your question to include a [mcve] that illustrates the problem you're having.

Comment: My code is too long. The matter is simple as anyone knows how a tkinker works. By default, TopLevel adapts to the size of the content, but perfect and has no margins on the sides which makes it look pretty neat

Comment: Could the 'elements' use ```pack``` with ```padx```,```pady``` or ```ipadx```, ```ipady``` ?? or have a ```Frame``` inside Toplevel that has slightly smaller dimensions than Toplevel to make it seem like there is a margin??

Comment: _"My code is too long"_ - we don't need your full code. We need you to create a [mcve] specific to this question. There are many possible solutions, but they depend on how you're adding widgets to the window. Are you using `grid`? `pack`? `place`? Have you considered simply adding frames along the edges that correspond to the amount of margin you want? Or if using grid, have you considered having empty, fixed size rows and columns along the edge?

Answer (score 0):

The simplest solution is to put all of your widgets in a frame, then the frame inside the toplevel with padding around the edges.

The following example creates several labels inside the frame, and the frame is placed in the root window with a margin of 100 pixels all around it.

This example puts everything in the root window, but the same technique works with a `Toplevel` or any other widget.

```
import tkinter as tk

root = tk.Tk()
frame = tk.Frame(root, bd=1, relief="raised")
frame.pack(padx=100, pady=100)

for i in range(20):
    label = tk.Label(frame, text=f"Widget #{i+1}")
    label.pack()

root.mainloop()
```